Open Policy Agent - Retrive object within data json array on URL matches
I wrote a fine grained  rego policy for m2m and user application invoking rest api server.
The problem to solve is how to  retrive the right object within an array once the incoming path (like /api/v1/test/12456) matches  the  url pattern saved in a json object array, and applying others policy on method, client and user type fields.
I tried this
data , input and policy  are
**data**:
{
    "endpoints": [
        {
            "path": "/api/outbound/sisalute/[0-9][0-9]0-9]/anagrafica",
            "POST": {
                "nest": {
                    "usertype": [
                        "ISCRITTO"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "path": "/api/outbound/test/[0-9][a-z][0-9]/sani/[0-9][a-z]",
            "PUT": {
               
                "nest": {
                    "usertype": [
                        "ISCRITTO"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "path": "/api/outbound/pos/[0-9][0-9]",
            "GET": {
               
                "nest": {
                    "usertype": [
                        "ISCRITTO"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }

]
**input:**
{
    "path": "/api/outbound/test/3f4/sani/1r"
}
**policy**:
allow if {
    some i
    glob.match(data.endpoints[i].path, ["/"], input.path)
}

if evaluate this line only  glob.match(data.endpoints[i].path, ["/"], input.path) i get
[
    {
        "i": 1
    }
]


a json containing the correct object id
Expected result
Retrive the correct id for accessing others object fields  in other policy. If you suggest to change the structure of the data json array to make the process easier it is ok.
Thank you all
